# Select query fails to find record

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans

```
select > from TABLE where Column = VALUE
```

Works, but does not tell me when it does not find a matching value.

How do I know when no match is found?

I am using Netbeans Java with mysql database

Comment: you check rowcount. an empty result set is **NOT** an error. it's a perfectly valid result that happens to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You'll know no matches were found if zero rows are retuned.